Obtaining Rindler metric from observer's coordinate basis
Example 5.7 in Hartle's Gravity: An Introduction To Einstein's General Relativity shows that a tetrad for an observer undergoing hyperbolic motion in flat spacetime is given by
$$
\begin{align*}
(\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat{0}}(\tau))^\alpha&=(\cosh(a\tau), \sinh(a\tau), 0, 0) \\
(\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat{1}}(\tau))^\alpha&=(\sinh(a\tau), \cosh(a\tau), 0, 0) \\
(\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat{2}}(\tau))^\alpha&=(0, 0, 1, 0) \\
(\boldsymbol{e}_{\hat{3}}(\tau))^\alpha&=(0, 0, 0, 1)
\end{align*}
$$
It seems to me that these are orthonormal basis vectors expressed in coordinate basis components right?
I wonder if it is possible to find out $(\boldsymbol{e}_{0}(\tau))^\hat{\alpha}, (\boldsymbol{e}_{1}(\tau))^\hat{\alpha}, (\boldsymbol{e}_{2}(\tau))^\hat{\alpha}, (\boldsymbol{e}_{3}(\tau))^\hat{\alpha}$, i.e. coordinate basis vectors expressed in orthonormal basis components, from above orthonormal basis vectors. They can be used to compute Rindler metric tensor directly:
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{e}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{0} & \boldsymbol{e}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{1} & \boldsymbol{e}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{2} & \boldsymbol{e}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{3} \\ \boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{0} & \boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{1} & \boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{2} & \boldsymbol{e}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{3} \\ \boldsymbol{e}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{0} & \boldsymbol{e}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{1} & \boldsymbol{e}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{2} & \boldsymbol{e}_{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{3} \\ \boldsymbol{e}_{3}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{0} & \boldsymbol{e}_{3}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{1} & \boldsymbol{e}_{3}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{2} & \boldsymbol{e}_{3}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{3} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-(ax)^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\boldsymbol{e}_{i}\cdot\boldsymbol{e}_{j}=\eta_{\mu\nu}\boldsymbol{e}_{i}^\mu\boldsymbol{e}_{j}^\nu$ (not sure if this is the correct formula for dot product).

I am still not sure how to get coordinate basis vectors expressed in orthonormal basis components from orthonormal basis vectors but there is a way to get Rindler metric from Minkowski metric.
Coordinate basis of Rindler spacetime $\{\boldsymbol{e}'_{\alpha}\}$ are related to coordinate basis of Minkowski spacetime $\{\boldsymbol{e}_{\alpha}\}$ by
$$\boldsymbol{e}'_{\mu}=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}\boldsymbol{e}_{\nu}$$
where $\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\mu}$ is Jacobian. From Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, Rindler metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ can be calculated as follows:
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \boldsymbol{e}'_{\mu}\cdot \boldsymbol{e}'_{\nu} = \eta_{\alpha\beta}{\boldsymbol{e}'}_{\mu}^{\alpha} {\boldsymbol{e}'}_{\nu}^\beta = \eta_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^\nu}.$$
Rindler coordinates $(t', x', y', z')$ is related to inertial coordinates $(t, x, y, z)$ by
$$
\begin{align*}
t &= x'\sinh(at') \\
x &= x'\cosh(at') \\
y &= y' \\
z &= z'
\end{align*}
$$
We obtain
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}-(ax)^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
as expected.
